# How to assgin two diffrent url with java script code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a JS code , and i want to redirect user to two different URL - If he enter value in input box 1 so he should redirect to this Default url[https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30] else he put more than 1 so this URL [https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30&configoption[2]]

Here is the Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



    document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode == 1) {
            var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
            window.location.replace(" https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30");
        }
    });

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30&configoption[2]="+inputvalue);
    });
});
```

Please check and suggest the best idea.

Comment: is  your requirement is to redirect to different url's based on the input value ...If so keyCode is not the right way to check the inputValue .keycode represents a system and implementation dependent numerical code identifying the unmodified value of the pressed key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lfremy6z/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var inputVal = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    if( inputVal == 1){
        window.location.replace("https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30");
    }else{
        window.location.replace("https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30&configoption[2]=" + inputVal);
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" />
<button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

In jsfiddle window.location is not present so I added the code here.

Comment: Alexander Higgins, Its a working code. Thanks and can u tell me how to minus input value. ex - If user enter value 2 so it should take 1.

Comment: @Grapy Sorry I didn't get you. Are you looking for "If the user enters -2, then it should take take 1"???

Comment: @Grapy Have a look into the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lfremy6z/2/ . This is what you are looking at????

Comment: Buddy,  Alexander Higgins's code is working.  but the further requirement is , if user enter value 2 so it should take 1, if enter 3 so it must take 2.  sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the user after insert value then

Try this

```
$('#input').on('change',function(e) {
    var inputvalue = $("this").val();
    if (inputvalue == 1) {
        window.location.replace(" https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30");
    }else {
        window.location.replace(" https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30&configoption[2]="+inputvalue);
    }
});
```

I thing it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> try if else condition to dynamic the url :

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var inputvalue = $("#input").val(),
url = (inputvalue == 1) ? 'https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30' : 'https://manage.bagful.com.au/cart.php?a=add&pid=30&configoption[2]';
 window.location.replace(url);
});
```